# Loading data to temp table from staging table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, snowflake-schema

I have loaded CSV file into staging area. Now I want to shift this file to temporary table. For that I created 3 different schemas, ie STG ( for staging area ), TMP ( for temporary area ) and TGT ( for target area or datawarehouse). This is staging table on STG schema.

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA PRASHANT_DWH.STG TO ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE PRASHANT_DWH_STG_COUNTRY (
    ID NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
    COUNTRY_DESC VARCHAR(256)
    );
```

This is temp table on TMP schema. I have added few more constraints like maintenance columns and surrogate keys.

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA PRASHANT_DWH.TMP TO ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE PRASHANT_DWH_TMP_COUNTRY (
    ID NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
    COUNTRY_DESC VARCHAR(256),
    RCD_INS_TS TIMESTAMP, -- aaja ko date
    RCD_UPD_TS TIMESTAMP, -- aaja ko date, if updated then only updated date
    RCD_START_DI DATE, -- system date 
    RCD_CLOSE_DI DATE, -- future date  
    RCD_CLOSE_FLG VARCHAR(1),
    ID_SUR_KEY NUMBER NOT NULL, -- autogenerated, else key + 1, 
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_SUR_KEY) 
    );
```

And I tried to merge these two tables and insert maintenance column surrogate keys. but it kept showing errors

```
   MERGE TMP.PRASHANT_DWH_TMP_COUNTRY AS TC
   USING STG.PRASHANT_DWH_STG_COUNTRY AS SC
   ON PDTC.ID = PDSC.ID 
   WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE PDTC.ID_SUR_KEY = PDSC.ID + 1 
        INSERT (ID, COUNTRY_DESC,RCD_INS_TS,RCD_UPD_TS,RCD_START_DI,RCD_CLOSE_DI,RCD_CLOSE_FLG,ID_SUR_KEY) 
        VALUES (SC.ID,SC.COUNTRY_DESC,current_timestamp,current_timestamp,current_date,current_date,N,SC.ID + 1)
   WHEN NOT MATCHEN BY TARGET THEN 
        DELETE
```

Gives the errors:

```
SQL compilation error: 
  syntax error line 1 at position 6 unexpected 'TMP'. 
  syntax error line 5 at position 15 unexpected 'PDTC'. 
  syntax error line 6 at position 8 unexpected 'INSERT'. 
  syntax error line 6 at position 32 unexpected ','. 
  syntax error line 6 at position 43 unexpected ','. 
  syntax error line 6 at position 54 unexpected ','. 
  syntax error line 6 at position 67 unexpected ','. 
  syntax error line 6 at position 80 unexpected ','. 
  syntax error line 6 at position 94 unexpected ','. 
  syntax error line 6 at position 105 unexpected ')'. 
  syntax error line 7 at position 37 unexpected ','. 
  syntax error line 7 at position 55 unexpected ','. 
  syntax error line 7 at position 73 unexpected ','. 
  syntax error line 7 at position 86 unexpected ','. 
  syntax error line 7 at position 99 unexpected ','. 
  syntax error line 7 at position 101 unexpected ','. 
  syntax error line 7 at position 108 unexpected '+'. 
  syntax error line 7 at position 111 unexpected ')'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the final merge is missing a few things.

- the `INTO` after `MERGE`
- I also fully qualified the table name (maybe not needed)
- you use the alias `PDTC` & `PDSC` it they are `TC` & `SC`
- The `N` being inserted in `RCD_CLOSE_FLG`, is a char, so it needs to be wrapped in single quotes `'N'`

```
MERGE INTO PRASHANT_DWH.TMP.PRASHANT_DWH_TMP_COUNTRY AS TC
USING PRASHANT_DWH.STG.PRASHANT_DWH_STG_COUNTRY AS SC
    ON TC.ID = SC.ID 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE TC.ID_SUR_KEY = SC.ID + 1
    INSERT (ID, COUNTRY_DESC, RCD_INS_TS, RCD_UPD_TS, RCD_START_DI, RCD_CLOSE_DI, RCD_CLOSE_FLG, ID_SUR_KEY) 
    VALUES (SC.ID, SC.COUNTRY_DESC, current_timestamp, current_timestamp, current_date, current_date, 'N', SC.ID + 1)
WHEN NOT MATCHEN BY TARGET THEN DELETE
```

But the tail of your [MERGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html) SQL is a bit of a mess, and I am not sure how to fix it, as what you are trying to do is not clear to me.

The INSERT should be bound to a `WHEN MATCHED THEN` or `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN`
and your `WHEN NOT MATCHEN BY TARGET THEN DELETE` seems..

It ether should be `WHEN NOT MATCHEN THEN DELETE`, but that seems to interfere with the INSERT.

It makes the most sense to UPDATE & Insert, and ignore the DELETE path,

```
MERGE INTO PRASHANT_DWH.TMP.PRASHANT_DWH_TMP_COUNTRY AS TC
USING PRASHANT_DWH.STG.PRASHANT_DWH_STG_COUNTRY AS SC
    ON TC.ID = SC.ID 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE TC.ID_SUR_KEY = SC.ID + 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ID, COUNTRY_DESC, RCD_INS_TS, RCD_UPD_TS, 
        RCD_START_DI, RCD_CLOSE_DI, RCD_CLOSE_FLG, ID_SUR_KEY) 
    VALUES (SC.ID, SC.COUNTRY_DESC, current_timestamp, 
        current_timestamp, current_date, current_date, 'N', 
        SC.ID + 1);
```